# Adobe Business Catalyst Search Filtering

Tags: search, business-catalyst

I have a product in business catalyst and have the property are. Color, Size, Price.
Can I filter that on the search results page. Like I want to search: iphone 5, red
Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the search filtering using javascript.

Before search is launched all products are invisible. If a user selects a certain parameter-attribute (e.g. red color), javascript performs search among all products, and makes those products visible, that respond to search conditions.

Comment: This only works if all your products are rendered on one page, but if you have more than 100 products and you want to render them all on one page it gets too much for the user.
It doesn't work when you have paginated content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard search provided in your BC system to search your products just make sure your product has the keyword so the system can find it, alternatively you can use the search filter.

FIRSTLY TRY:

**SITE MANAGER> SITE SEARCH and create a search form to search products or catalogue > make sure your product contains the keywords.**

SECONDLY TRY(MORE RECOMMENDED!):
Navigate to your template by going to **SITE MANAGER> PAGE TEMPLATES> CREATE OR EDIT A TEMPLATE> USE THE MODULES WIDGET>ECOMMERCE>PRODUCTS>PRODUCTS SEARCH FORM**

If you don't like the look go to code view and remove the table or BC code and style it your way.

The second one is tested and its a very powerful search VERY FAST!

Answer (score 0):

BC has a price filter through the URL.

Example:

```
mysite.com/catalogue?Filter=Price&PriceFrom=0&PriceTo=200
```

Comment: Very good and accurate answer, but this works only in catalogs, it doesn't work in the search results.